# ディクショナリの要素のリスト化

Tags: python

nx.short_path_lengthを使用して、辞書型で取得したノード毎の
始点からの距離を、リストとして抽出したいのですが、以下のコードだと
エラーが出てしまいました。どうしたらよいでしょうか？

```py
d=nx.shortest_path_length(G,source="一般顧客",target=None)
f=list(d.values())
node_color=[f[node] for node in G.nodes()]
node_color
```

```py
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-3dc896932224> in <module>
      1 d=nx.shortest_path_length(G,source="一般顧客",target=None)
      2 f=list(d.values())
----> 3 node_color=[f[node] for node in G.nodes()]
      4 node_color

<ipython-input-44-3dc896932224> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 d=nx.shortest_path_length(G,source="一般顧客",target=None)
      2 f=list(d.values())
----> 3 node_color=[f[node] for node in G.nodes()]
      4 node_color

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1):

まず

```
G.nodes()
```

の中身を確認してください。要素が文字列になっていませんか？
そのためにf[node]でエラーになっています。

場合によっては、辞書のdをそのまま使って

```
node_color = [d[node] for node in G.nodes()]
```

でも希望の値が得られるかもしれません。